# PigStorage() isn't storing the query output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

```
grunt> STORE highest_rated into ‘output1’ USING PigStorage(‘,’);
<line 5, column 25>  Unexpected character ''
2020-12-03 00:41:58,877 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 5, column 25>  Unexpected character ''
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1606982853354.log
grunt> STORE highest_rated into ‘output1’ USING PigStorage(‘,’)
>> 
>>
```

Why is grunt showing '>>' instead of storing the output?
I am writing this in Cloudera

Comment: Please can you include more details into your question for us to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Typo - you're missing a semicolon. Also, you have nothing to store (read the error)... `highest_rated` was never assigned because you used smart-quotes, not a `'` character around `‘output1’`, and same with `PigStorage(‘,’);`